# Создание конструкции try catch с помощью dnlib

Tags: c#, исключения, cil, dnlib

Есть программа на C# которая добавляет в exe файл конструкцию try catch. В try специально кладется мусорный опкод (calli null), а в catch сам код метода. Посмотрел IL код в декомпиле, вроде все должно работать, но сам выходной файл не запускается. Почему? Как исправить?

```
using System.Linq;
using dnlib.DotNet;
using dnlib.DotNet.Emit;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string pt = "prog.exe";
        // Загрузка сборки
        var module = ModuleDefMD.Load(pt);

        // Перебираем все типы в сборке
        foreach (var type in module.Types)
        {
            // Перебираем все методы в типе
            foreach (var method in type.Methods)
            {
                if (!method.HasBody) continue;
                if (method.Name == ".ctor" || method.Name == ".cctor") continue;
                method.Body.Instructions.Insert(0, new Instruction(OpCodes.Calli, null));
                ExceptionHandler item2 = new ExceptionHandler(ExceptionHandlerType.Catch)
                {
                    HandlerStart = method.Body.Instructions[1],
                    HandlerEnd = method.Body.Instructions[method.Body.Instructions.Count - 1],
                    TryEnd = method.Body.Instructions[1],
                    TryStart = method.Body.Instructions[0]
                };
                method.Body.ExceptionHandlers.Add(item2);
                //method.Body.OptimizeBranches();
                //method.Body.OptimizeMacros();
                //method.Body.KeepOldMaxStack = true;
                
            }
        }

        // Сохраняем измененную сборку
        var writerOptions = new dnlib.DotNet.Writer.ModuleWriterOptions(module);
        writerOptions.Logger = DummyLogger.NoThrowInstance;
        module.Write(pt + "___protected.exe", writerOptions);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если опкод мусорный, как же он будет работать? Операндом calli должна быть валидная сигнатура функции, пробуйте с nop, если нужна ничего не делающая инструкция.

Comment: Так вы почитайте внимательно, поймите логику... Я специально добавил мусорный опкод в блок try, чтобы сразу перейти к блоку catch. Все очень логично и должно работать, но программа на выходе не запускается

Comment: Не логично, если вспомнить о том, что при некорректном IL все встанет раком еще до момента выполнения метода... Проще всего взять за пример корректный IL, сгенерированный компилятором C#, и генерировать по аналогии.

Comment: Ок. Даже если поставить просто NOP, то все равно программа не запускается. В чем причина?

Comment: Это было не единственной проблемой. Например, внутри блока catch нельзя использовать инструкцию ret, а она есть в конце каждого метода. Так что ваш код как есть, похоже, в принципе не может заработать.

Comment: Я сейчас смотрю в dnSpy, там везде ret вне блока catch. Так в чем тогда проблема может быть? Все же вроде правильно

Comment: Попробуйте прогнать модифицированную сборку через PEVerify: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/peverify-exe-peverify-tool Потенциальных проблем тут может быть очень много. Следующая проблема на очереди: если у метода есть возвращаемое значение, перед инструкцией ret на стеке должно быть правильное число аргументов. Если слепо обрезать по последней инструкции, это правило нарушится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Операндом calli является сигнатура функции, поэтому использовать `new Instruction(OpCodes.Calli, null)` нельзя. Я заменил calli на nop, попробовал прогнать вашу программу через минимальное консольное приложение ("Hello, world"), и вот что выяснил. Вы добавляете блок catch, но не задаете тип исключений, который надо обрабатывать. Проще всего задать тип Object, чтобы ловить все исключения:

```
ExceptionHandler item2 = new ExceptionHandler(ExceptionHandlerType.Catch)
{
    HandlerStart = method.Body.Instructions[1],
    HandlerEnd = method.Body.Instructions[method.Body.Instructions.Count - 1],
    TryEnd = method.Body.Instructions[1],
    TryStart = method.Body.Instructions[0],
    CatchType = module.CorLibTypes.Object.TypeRef
};
```

Если сделать это изменение, попробовать еще раз и прогнать полученную сборку через [PEVerify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/peverify-exe-peverify-tool), получаем указание на следующую проблему:

> [IL]: Ошибка: [D:...\prog.exe___protected.exe : Prog.Program::Main][смещение
> 0x0000000C] передача управления в конец блока исключения
> Ошибок при проверке: 1 prog.exe___protected.exe

В конце блока обработки исключения должна всегда быть инструкция выхода наружу. То есть чтобы IL был корректен, он должен выглядеть так:

```
.method public hidebysig static void Main() cil managed
{
 .maxstack  1

 .try
 {
           // Содержимое try        
           leave.s      IL_0001
 }
 catch [mscorlib]System.Exception
 {
           // Содержимое catch  
           leave.s      IL_0001
 }
 IL_0001: ret          
}
```

Это в самом простом случае, когда метод не имеет возвращаемого значения. Если метод возвращает значение, перед ret еще должна быть инструкция, загружающие это значение на стек. Подробнее об инструкциях и как они работают можно узнать в спецификации [ECMA-335](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-335/), третий раздел.